# Наследование в Java, extends

Tags: java, ооп, наследование

У меня имеется

```
public class BasicEnemy extends GameObject{ /*а тут должно быть еще и extends Enemies*/
...
}
```

Мне требуется сделать абстрактный класс, аля:

```
public abstract class Enemies{
...
}
```

Но, как быть если у меня класс BasicEnemy уже наследует GameObject (без него не обойтись).

Comment: Использовать интерфейс вместо абстрактного класса.

Comment: Что Вам мешает написать `public abstract class Enemies extends GameObject` и `public class BasicEnemy extends Enemies `? Если действительно есть веская причина, то только interface, как советует Сергей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наследование в Java иерархическое: вы можете определить класс `GameObject`, от него еще какой-нибудь

```
class GameObjSubСlass extends GameObject { 
  void doSomething() {...}
  ... 
}
```

от него - еще один

```
class GameObjSubSubСlass extends GameObjSubСlass { 
  void doSomethingElse() {...}
  ... 
}
```

от него, в свою очередь, еще субкласс(ы)

```
class DangerousEnemy extends GameObjSubSubСlass { 
  void doSomethingSpecial() {...}
  ... 
}
class DreadfulEnemy extends GameObjSubSubСlass { ... }
```

и так далее. Любой класс из иерархии наследования будет иметь те методы и поля, которые определены в любом из его предков: объекту класса `GameObjSubСlass` будут доступны методы `doSomething()`, `doSomethingElse()` и `doSomethingSpecial()`.
Если вы хотите, чтобы классы из разных иерархий обладали какими-то общими чертами, то следует описать интерфейс с методами, описывающими эти общие черты, и реализовать в каждом из таких классов методы этих интерфейсов. Например, если вы хотите, чтобы некоторые типы друзей и некоторые типы врагов умели летать, а другие умели ползать, то можно сделать что-то типа такого:

```
class GameObject {
  // write methods as needed  
}

class Enemy extends GameObject { 
  void fight() { /* your code */ }
  // write more methods as needed  
} 

class Friend extends GameObject { 
  void embrace() { /* your code */ } 
  // write more methods as needed  
} 

interface CanFly { void fly(); }
interface CanCrawl { void crawl(); }

class FlyingFriend extends Friend implements CanFly {
  public void fly() { /* your code */ }
}

class CrawlingFriend extends Friend implements CanCrawl {
  public void crawl() { /* your code */ }
}

class FlyingEnemy extends Enemy implements CanFly {
  public void fly() { /* your code */ }
}

class CrawlingEnemy extends Enemy implements CanCrawl {
  // Рожденный ползать летать не может!
  public void crawl() { /* your code */ }
}

class TerribleEnemy extends Enemy 
  implements CanFly, CanCrawl {
  // Этот может и ползать, и летать - ужас!
  public void crawl() { /* your code */ }
  public void fly() { /* your code */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

в java нельзя делать множественное наследование, используйте интерфейс

Comment: В каком это смысле нельзя? Поясните. К примеру у меня есть абстракция GG и от нее пляшет абстракция CC, в свою очередь от СС есть уже дочерний класс Player с реализацией переопределенных функции из CC|GG

Comment: @GenCloud Множественное в том смысле что вы никак не сможете объявить класс следующим образом  class A extends B,C,D{}

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov , это ясное дело, но речь то шла об объединении исполняемых функции аналогичных классов по свойствам в одну абстракцию